# Android 2.3 SipDemo Failed to register

Tags: android, registration, sip, voip

I have tried the SipDemo as a starting point of developing a softphone but have not yet modified the code. My sip credentials entered on SipDemo are working on other softphones and did a double check whether they are correct or not. The error code returned is -4(No data connection). I'm using an HTC wildfire S with android 2.3 as my testing handset.

When I googled around, I found that someone had the same problem and his solution was to hardcode tcp because the handset was not working with udp hence the "registration failed" message was shown.

Comment: I have [the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30241756/failed-to-create-sipsession-network-unavailable), did you manage to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do anything apart from hardcoding the IP, if the device itself doesn't support udp. Some HTC devices are known to fail.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8407